# Is it possible to apply monkeypatching on the Object's default getter/setter?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm looking for the method that `Object` or `Array` use internally when executing:

```
var x = { a: 1 }
// getters
x['a'] // or x.a
// setters
x['a'] = 1 // or x.a = 1
```

Same for arrays

```
var a = [0, 1]
// getter
a[0]
// setter
a[0] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have two alternatives:

- `defineProperty` contains "set" and "get" attributes. You could apply this thing for every property that you need to be declared.
- Using proxies (requires ecmascript 6) you can declare a getter and a setter and this will be applied for every property.

Comment: Pardon me for being pedantic about terminology, but in JavaScript/ECMAScript members of objects are called "properties", not "attributes". An Attribute is something else completely: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-attribute

Comment: Good Point @Dai. I fixed that, thanks for your feedback!